# Selecting (and subtracting) from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very simple data frame (portfolio_df) containing a basic portfolio, and I would like to be able to sell/subtract a random number of each stock (based on the contents of the dataframe).

```
    Name      Number_of_shares
0   MMM             420.00
1   AXP             633.00
2   AAPL           3121.00
3   Cash         100057.58
```

It's easy to subtract say 10 from each item,

```
portfolio_df["Number_of_shares"] -= 10
```

but I can't figure out how to subtract between 0 and 420 from MMM, 0 and 633 from AXP etc, as

```
portfolio_df["Number_of_shares"] -= random(0, portfolio_df["Number_of_shares"])
```

yields

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Also, Noob, so simple answers I can understand are preferred over elegant/complex ones I cannot. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to multiply the column with a random number between 0 and 1. So you can do:

```
portfolio_df["Number_of_shares"] *= np.random.uniform(0,1, len(portfolio_df))
```

Comment: My thought, exactly!  Also, `np.random.rand` is ***U(0, 1)*** so this is equivalent `np.random.rand(len(df))`

Comment: Quang, That works! Can you tell me where I add np.floor so I end up with say 210, 315 and 407, instead of 210.873, 315.9973 and 407.23844?

Comment: @Mike do a `portfolio_df['Number...'] = portfolio_df['Number...'].astype(int)` afterward?

Comment: @Mike Not bad, but I think that is counterintuitive, so there is better one.